# My C code is not running in Microsoft VS CODE

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, runtime-error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter the value of a\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter the value of b\n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("The sum of a and b is %d", a + b);
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this code in Microsoft Visual Code the code doesn't stop executing nor do i get the output. It starts running but it does not stop. I am also not getting any output. Other type of code is working perfectly fine.
Anyone can help me with this?
[click here for  image from vscode showing the running window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTjwh.png)

Comment: What happens after it asks you to input something? Did you manage to print something at the runtime?

Comment: first get rid of all the spaces in your file path, try it on something else than OneDrive

Comment: it does not even ask me to input..it simply keeps running without any output..check the image i have provided

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why code is not running is because it is running in "Output" Window, which I had shown in the linked Image.
If you want to run code properly then you have to run it in "Terminal" Window.

For running your code in "Terminal" window you have to follow these steps:
Step 1: Open Settings.
Step 2: Then type "Run in Terminal" in search box of the setting. Scroll below and find that setting.[Install code runner if you haven't.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRbid.png)
Step 3: Tick the box which is in 2nd line.

After that your code will run properly.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have written is 100% correct.
Take care of the following things, check it out, if you have done them:

1. Install gcc in your system. gcc helps u compile c or c++ codes.
2. Install a C/C++ extension from the extensions section in the visual studio code.
3. At last, if the situation is still the same, try to re-install the visual studio code.

I hope, this might helps you. If you liked my suggestion, please press the upvoke button to motivate me to write such answers for you.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if this thing happens again first again try to execute the same code with some other IDE or run your code separately with CMD or PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Code runner extension runs code in the output file which can not be interacted with. You have to change it so it runs in the terminal.
Go to the menu Code > Preferences > Settings.
In the User tab on the left panel, expand the Extensions section.
Find and select Run Code Configuration.
Find and check the box Run in Terminal.

Answer (score -3):

I had exact same problem and it turns out I forgot to save the code:)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32398200)

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/)